# Facing issue in establishing Pyspark session

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am trying to connect two database Postgres and Sql Server.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.jars", "mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark1 = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.jars", "postgresql-42.2.5.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

i am able to read data from Postgres database, when i am creating only on spark session as below

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.jars", "mssql-jdbc-8.4.1.jre8.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

i am able to connect to Sql Server. I am new to Pyspark, please suggest me how to connect to two databases by using a Single session. Please help. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can put multiple jars in the same Spark session, in your `spark` you only add `mssql` jar while `spark1` only add `postgresql` jar, that's why you can't connect the postgres in `spark`. In fact, you can add multiple jar in the same session like `.config("spark.jars.packages", "jar1,jar2,...")`.